# Pass variable from content to layout in Nanoc using Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, slim-lang, nanoc

I basically want to know the easiest way to pass a ruby variable from a content page to its layout using Nanoc and Slim. I am thinking of something like this:

content/content.slim:

```
---
title: Writeups
layout: /layout.slim
---
- age = get_age
```

layout/layout.slim:

```
doctype html
  html
    head
      == yield
      p I am #{@item[:title]} and am #{@item[:age]} years old
```

I know how to access values via frontmatter, but frontmatter values are fixed and what I want is a ruby function to find that value for me.

Comment: does nanoc have the `content_for` method available?

Comment: I had to use `include` instead of `content_for`. It is related to the version of nanoc you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nanoc provides a [capturing helper](https://nanoc.ws/doc/reference/helpers/#capturing), which makes it possible to “capture” content in one place and use it somewhere else.

content/content.slim:

```
---
title: Mister Tree
---

p Hello there!

- content_for :age
  | hundreds of years
```

layout/layout.slim:

```
doctype html
html
  body
    == yield
    p I am #{@item[:title]} and am #{content_for(@item, :age)} years old
```

lib/default.rb (or any file in lib/ of your choosing):

```
use_helper Nanoc::Helpers::Capturing
```

This generates the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Hello there!</p>
    <p>I am Mister Tree and am hundreds of years years old</p>
  </body>
</html>
```